# How to properly form ChatGPT API request body with the functions parameter?

Tags: openai-api, chatgpt-api

I'm sending the following API request to ChatGPT for which I need the structured result:

```json
{
    "model": "gpt-3.5-turbo",
    "messages": [
      {
        "role": "system",
        "content": "You are an art expert."
      },
      {
        "role": "user",
        "content": "List similar artists to Pablo Picasso."
      }  
    ],
    "functions": [
        {
            "name": "get_similar_artists",
            "description": "Similar artists",
            "parameters": {
                "type": "object",
                "properties": {
                    "similarArtists": {
                        "type": "array",
                        "description": "Similar artists",
                        "items": {
                            "type": "string",
                            "desctiption": "Artist name"
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

The result always list just one artist, the Pablo Picasso itself.

```json
{
    "id": "chatcmpl-8FzRKhdvnNmeQlKqO706oahxZd2Rl",
    "object": "chat.completion",
    "created": 1698821786,
    "model": "gpt-3.5-turbo-0613",
    "choices": [
        {
            "index": 0,
            "message": {
                "role": "assistant",
                "content": null,
                "function_call": {
                    "name": "get_similar_artists",
                    "arguments": "{\n  \"similarArtists\": [\"Pablo Picasso\"]\n}"
                }
            },
            "finish_reason": "function_call"
        }
    ],
    "usage": {
        "prompt_tokens": 64,
        "completion_tokens": 22,
        "total_tokens": 86
    }
}
```

But if I remove the `functions` section from the original request, the response correctly lists 10 different artists like this:

```json
{
    "id": "chatcmpl-8FzXpEyhGGoO0CIRbHQlQdHsv9Pvx",
    "object": "chat.completion",
    "created": 1698822189,
    "model": "gpt-3.5-turbo-0613",
    "choices": [
        {
            "index": 0,
            "message": {
                "role": "assistant",
                "content": "1. Georges Braque - Braque was a close friend and collaborator of Picasso, often considered the co-founder of Cubism along with him.\n\n2. Juan Gris - Gris was another prominent figure of Cubism and was greatly influenced by Picasso's work. His paintings often showcased geometric shapes and fragmented forms.\n\n3. Fernand Léger - Léger, like Picasso, experimented with various styles throughout his career. His works often displayed bold colors, simplified forms, and elements of Cubism.\n\n4. Salvador Dali - While Dali's style differs from Picasso's, both artists were significant figures in the Surrealist movement. Dali's dreamlike and fantastical imagery set him apart, but he, like Picasso, had a profound impact on modern art.\n\n5. Joan Miró - Miró's unique and imaginative style shared certain themes with Picasso's work. Both artists often used symbolism and abstraction to convey their ideas, with Miró focusing more on a sense of playfulness and childlike wonder.\n\n6. Marc Chagall - Chagall's vibrant and dreamlike paintings often expressed a sense of nostalgia and folklore. Although his style differs from Picasso's, their shared interest in expressing emotion through color and form makes them comparable.\n\n7. Henri Matisse - Matisse, known for his bold use of color and expressive brushwork, was a contemporary of Picasso and a leading figure of Fauvism. While their styles differ, both artists were known for pushing the boundaries of traditional art.\n\n8. Wassily Kandinsky - Kandinsky was a pioneer of abstract art and a co-founder of the Blue Rider movement. His emphasis on color, shape, and spirituality aligns with Picasso's exploration of unconventional styles and subjects.\n\n9. Max Ernst - Ernst, a German artist associated with Surrealism and Dadaism, shared Picasso's interest in experimental techniques and subject matter. Both artists often incorporated elements of collage and symbolism in their works.\n\n10. Francis Bacon - Bacon, an Irish-born artist, was heavily influenced by Picasso's distorted and emotive depictions of the human figure. Bacon's paintings often conveyed a sense of anguish and existentialism, much like Picasso's works during his Blue and Rose periods."
            },
            "finish_reason": "stop"
        }
    ],
    "usage": {
        "prompt_tokens": 24,
        "completion_tokens": 454,
        "total_tokens": 478
    }
}
```

I don't quite understand what am I doing wrong and what should I do to get a structured JSON response with the names of these 10 similar artists?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you aren't using the API properly. From the docs, [take a look at the function calling code](https://platform.openai.com/docs/guides/function-calling), where you can see examples of how to use this feature.

Your function definitions need to be passed as an array of objects under the `tools` parameter. See the docs for more. Hope this helps!